# How to implement loader after form validation using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

My idea is to show loader circle after clicking a form submit button, because it's take some time to redirect user to page which let you know that form is submitted successfully. But with my limited JavaScrip knowledge I can't figure it out how to start loader only if user have filed out all required fields. Is it possible using JavaScript?

Here is my HTML code:

```
        <form id="form">
          <input type="text" required>
          <button type="submit" class="button" onclick="this.classList.toggle('button--loading')">
            <span class="button__text">Save</span>
          </button>
        </form>
```

and CSS code:

```
.button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  background: #009579;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:active {
  background: #007a63;
}

.button__text {
  font: bold 20px "Quicksand", san-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.button--loading .button__text {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.button--loading::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: button-loading-spinner 1s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes button-loading-spinner {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0turn);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should research using an `submit` event handler on your form, preventing automatic submission with `event.preventDefault()`. Check to see if all fields are filled out. If not, don't continue. If so, trigger the loading code and allow the form to submit. I think you'll want your form to submit via ajax and then use JS to redirect the page afterwards if you want your loading code to stay on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your HTML slightly and also have to add this JS function:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return submitTheForm(this);">
    <input type="text" required>
    <button type="submit" class="button">
        <span class="button__text">Save</span>
    </button>
</form>

<script>
    function submitTheForm(theForm){
        const eButton = theForm.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');
        eButton.classList.toggle('button--loading');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only replace start and end animation

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(form);
  const url = "your url here";
  const options = {
     method: "POST",
     body: data
  } 
  // start animation
  fetch(url, options)
   .finally(() => {
     // end animation
   });
}

form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```